# Create dynamic columns using information from existing columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Data Frame

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'text':["random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101",
                           "random text with pol # as 222",
                           "random text with ein # as 333 and ein no as 303"],
                   'label':[
                           [[26,29,"pol"],[44,47,"ein"]],
                           [[26,29,"pol"]],
                           [[26,29,"ein"],[44,47,"ein"]] ]})
```

Giving this output

```
                                              text                      label
0  random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101  [[26,29,pol],[44,47,ein]]
1                    random text with pol # as 222               [[26,29,pol]
2  random text with ein # as 333 and ein no as 303  [[26,29,ein],[44,47,ein]]
```

I want this output

```
                                              text                      label  \
0  random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101  [[26,29,pol],[44,47,ein]]   
1                    random text with pol # as 222               [[26,29,pol]   
2  random text with ein # as 303 and ein no as 304  [[26,29,ein],[44,47,ein]]   

   pol ein_1 ein_2  
0  111   101        
1  222              
2        303   304
```

I want to create columns dynamically using column information `label` where this column is a list of list one list contains start_index , end_index, label_type . By accessing the text in the `text` column using the start and end index we can get the actual label.

For eg `text` : "random text with pol # as 222" and `label` is '[[26,29,pol]'

so pol = Text[26:29] which is pol = 222

so I have to create pol as a column name and give it value 222.

so Far I could come up with this

```
dd["pol"] = dd.apply(lambda row: row.text[ row.label[0][0] : row.label[0][1]], axis=1)
```

This only works if the data is static and every time all data labels comes once and in the same place.

Comment: Is this a strict format without variations?

Comment: No, it is not a static format as in the example the label has 3 rows with 3 different formats. 1 st row has POL and EIN ;
2 nd row has  only one POL;
3rd row has two EIN .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a  generic way to this. This will work for labels other than **pol** and **ein** as well if you have it in your df, and will generate columns dynamically for all of them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def check_labels(row):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for l in row.label:
        d[l[2]].append(int(row.text[l[0] : l[1]]))
    return d

label_df = dd.apply(check, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)

label_df1 = pd.DataFrame()    
for col in label_df.columns.tolist():
    max_values = int(label_df[col].str.len().max())
    cols = [col+'_'+str(i+1) for i in range(max_values)] if max_values > 1 else [col]
    label_df1[cols] = label_df[col].apply(pd.Series)

dd = pd.concat([dd,label_df1], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> dd
                                              text                           label    pol  ein_1  ein_2
0  random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101  [[26, 29, pol], [44, 47, ein]]  111.0  101.0    NaN
1                    random text with pol # as 222                 [[26, 29, pol]]  222.0    NaN    NaN
2  random text with ein # as 333 and ein no as 303  [[26, 29, ein], [44, 47, ein]]    NaN  333.0  303.0
```

#### Steps:

First create a function `check_labels` to use information in `label` column and extract relevant data from `text` column.

Apply this function on your `df`, which returns a series of dictionaries containing **labels** and their extracted **values**. Apply **`pandas.Series`** to it and save results into `label_df`:

```
>>> label_df = dd.apply(check, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
>>> label_df
     pol         ein
0  [111]       [101]
1  [222]         NaN
2    NaN  [333, 303]
```

Now we need to count max no. of values in each label obtained above, and split data according to that count for each label. So as `pol` label has maximum 1 value in each row, it will be kept as is, but `ein` has 2 values in row 2, so it will be split up as `ein_1` and `ein_2`:

```
>>> label_df1 = pd.DataFrame()    
>>> for col in label_df.columns.tolist():
...     max_values = int(label_df[col].str.len().max())
...     cols = [col+'_'+str(i+1) for i in range(max_values)] if max_values > 1 else [col]
...     label_df1[cols] = label_df[col].apply(pd.Series)
... 
>>> label_df1
     pol  ein_1  ein_2
0  111.0  101.0    NaN
1  222.0    NaN    NaN
2    NaN  333.0  303.0
```

We now concat this **label_df1** back to original df **dd** to get what you wanted:

```
>>> dd = pd.concat([dd,label_df1], axis=1)
>>> dd
                                              text                           label    pol  ein_1  ein_2
0  random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101  [[26, 29, pol], [44, 47, ein]]  111.0  101.0    NaN
1                    random text with pol # as 222                 [[26, 29, pol]]  222.0    NaN    NaN
2  random text with ein # as 333 and ein no as 303  [[26, 29, ein], [44, 47, ein]]    NaN  333.0  303.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only do it in several steps

```
dd_tmp = dd.text.str.extractall(r"(pol|ein) (?:#|no) as (\d+)")
```

Which outputs

```
           0    1
  match
0 0      pol  111
  1      ein  101
1 0      pol  222
2 0      ein  333
  1      ein  303
```

And then, step by step

```
dd_tmp.columns = ["name", "value"]
dd_tmp = dd_tmp.reset_index()
dd_tmp["name"] = dd_tmp["name"] + "_" + dd_tmp["match"].astype(str)
dd_tmp = dd_tmp.pivot(columns="name", index="level_0", values="value")
```

And when joined with original dataframe (`on` not specified, so join by index)

```
>>> dd.join(dd_tmp)
                                              text                           label ein_0 ein_1 pol_0
0  random text with pol # as 111 and ein no as 101  [[26, 29, pol], [44, 47, ein]]   NaN   101   111
1                    random text with pol # as 222                 [[26, 29, pol]]   NaN   NaN   222
2  random text with ein # as 333 and ein no as 303  [[26, 29, ein], [44, 47, ein]]   333   303   NaN
```

Comment: Haven't considered that `label` field consists of location of variables of interest and created more complex solution.